# wolfSSL and StellarisWare examples

Tags: ssl, stellaris, wolfssl

I want to use the freertos_demo that is part of StellarisWare /TivaWare in combination with wolfSSL library but I find it difficult to read the Makefile (actually the makedefs files).

I downloaded and compiled wolfSSL according to the manual. Now in /usr/local/lib there are the following files:

- /usr/local/lib//libwolfssl.la
- /usr/local/lib//libwolfssl.so
- /usr/local/lib//libwolfssl.so.3
- /usr/local/lib//libwolfssl.so.3.1.0

Now I open makedefs from the StellarisWare root directory and added the folling code to line 160:

`LIBS=-lwolfssl`
Further, I modified lines *246* and *252* which now state the following (both lines are identical; basically I only added  `'${LIBS}'` ):

`'${LIBM}' '${LIBC}' '${LIBGCC}' '${LIBS}';`

However, when I go to the blinky sub-directory and perform a "make clean; make", I get the following error:

`arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lwolfssl`

What am I missing?

Best

Comment: Did you try adding -L/usr/local/lib/ ?

Answer (score 1):

per the suggestion from @nettrino it looks like /usr/local/lib is not in your system LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. You could confirm this from a terminal by using this command

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Do you see /usr/local/lib? If not you can do one of two things.

**Option 1: Follow @nettrino's intended suggestion and in the Makefile change the line:**

```
LIBS=-lwolfssl
```

to

```
LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -lwolfssl
```

**Option 2: Edit your .bash_profile (or .bashrc) and add the line:**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib"
```

Then reload the terminal to get the updated changes or use the command

```
source .bash_profile
```

(or source .bashrc depending on which one you edited)

Then try the same echo command again and do you now see /usr/local/lib
in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?